# Python sort with last added element in the queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

Actually my sort algorithm works, but there is a problem.
I have a class namely SortedItem which includes

```
def __init__(self, point, cost):
    self.coordinate = point
    self.cost = cost
```

and I have also priority queue which sorts the this SortedItem by its cost:

```
class PriorityQueue:

def __init__(self):
    self.items = []

def isEmpty(self):
    return self.items == []

def sortComparatorByCost(self, item):
    return item.cost

def enqueue(self, item):
    self.items.append(item)
    self.items.sort(key=self.sortComparatorByCost, reverse=True)


def dequeue(self):
    return self.items.pop()

def returnQueueAsString(self):
    queue_str = ""
    for eachItem in self.items:
        queue_str += str(eachItem) + " "
    return queue_str

def isQueueContainsElement(self, element):
    for eachElement in self.items:
        if eachElement[0] == element:
            return True
    return False
```

The problem occurs here:
- I have defined some order to add queue. Let's say I am adding this objects to the queue:

```
obj1 = SortedItem((1,0), 10))
queue.enqueue(obj1)
obj2 = SortedItem((2,0), 15))
queue.enqueue(obj2)
obj3 = SortedItem((2,1), 15))
queue.enqueue(obj3)
```

- Now I have to get objects from queue in this order (obj1, obj2, obj3).
- However python built-in sort function sort these objects like this: (obj1, obj3, obj2) (because obj2 and obj3 has the same cost)
- How can i solve this issue. I mean If 2 objects cost is the same, I should get the first added one.

**Note that: I have just created a simple example of my problem. If you try this code you may get the objects in this order: obj1, obj2, obj3**

Comment: Hint: Python sort is stable.

Comment: By the way -- why don't you use Python's builtin PQ?

Comment: @user202729 that's means?

Comment: @user202729 I couldn't understand built-in priority queue in python. This way is more understandable for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of sorting the items in reverse order and removing them from the right,

> ```
> def enqueue(self, item):
>     self.items.append(item)
>     self.items.sort(key=self.sortComparatorByCost, reverse=True)
>
> def dequeue(self):
>     return self.items.pop()
> ```

you could remove them from the left. That would avoid reversing the order of insertion of the items with the same cost.

```
def enqueue(self, item):
    self.items.append(item)
    self.items.sort(key=self.sortComparatorByCost)

def dequeue(self):
    return self.items.pop(0)
```

Removing items from the beginning of a list [is not efficient](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), however, so you could better use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) (replacing `pop(0)` by `popleft()`) to fix that. A `deque` on the other hand, has no in-place `sort()` method, so would need to replace `self.items.sort()` by `self.items = deque(sorted(self.items))` as well.

Comment: @monstereo You're right, that didn't work as I thought. I've found a better solution.